# Find and replace words on Microsoft Word with a proper case

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I came across a problem that I want to replace a string on Microsoft Word, say "ABC" with "abcdef". I thought it would be something very easy to do using control+H "Find & replace function" but it turns out that Word replaces with "ABCDEF" instead of "abcdef", which baffled me. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After , click on "More" then select "Match case".  "Match case" applies to both what you're searching for and what you're replacing it with.

Comment: Thank you for your help!